# Transferring standalone wordpress blog to the one under **.wordpress.com

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, migration

I have a [blog](http://eren.0fees.net/blog/) that is working on wordpress installation and now I want to transfer it to the my new blog under WordPress.com domain name. Is it possible to carry all the content to new WordPress blog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're dealing with a WordPress.com hosted site, then you don't have direct DB access. You'll need to export out your content, and import it into the new site using the options in the WP admin area. You also may not be able to use the same theme. WordPress.com hosted sites have way more restrictions than other hosting options.

Answer (score 0):

Login to Wordpress Dashboard > Tools > Export > All content and attachments
Login to New Wordpress Dashboard > Tools > Import > Wordpress > Install Plugin > Select the fie written by previous process and upload.